# Why do I get Invalid identifier error even though column exist

Tags: oracle

```
WITH distinct_appl_temp AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    c_number
   ,j_group
   ,pi_c_dt
   ,act_can
  FROM app_fact vd
  WHERE
      vd.c_number   = 12335
    AND vd.act_can    = 1
    AND vd.pi_c_dt    = (
        SELECT
          MIN( v2.pi_c_dt )
        FROM app_fact v2
        WHERE
            v2.c_number   = vd.c_number
          AND v2.j_group    = vd.j_group
          AND v2.act_can    = vd.act_can
          AND add_months( v2.pi_c_dt,+6 ) > vd.pi_c_dt
      )
  GROUP BY
    vd.c_number
   ,vd.j_group
   ,vd.pi_c_dt
   ,vd.act_can
  ORDER BY
    vd.j_group
   ,vd.act_can
) SELECT
  dt.c_number
 ,dt.j_group
 ,dt.pi_c_dt
 ,dt.act_can
 ,da.pi_c_dt
FROM distinct_appl_temp dt
 ,   app_fact da
WHERE
    dt.c_number   = da.c_number
  AND dt.j_group    = da.j_group
  AND dt.pi_c_dt    = da.pi_c_dt
  AND dt.act_can    = da.act_can
```

Comment: Please format your code (like I did) and re-run the query.  Post the Error and the Line Number that is associated with the error.  In `SQL*Developer`, press `CTRL+F7` to format the code.

Comment: After formatting i see where the error is. How do i give you a credit?

Comment: Please inform us what the problem was (as a comment to the answer).  Thanks.

Comment: What column is it saying is wrong? If it is from a table we would need the table definition as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Code Review

1. **line 3-6**

   - Columns are not fully qualified
2. **line 2 & 21-25**

   - `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` doesn't make sense in this context.  drop one
3. **line 26-28**

   - I wouldn't trust an `ORDER BY` clause in a (refactored) sub-query. Move it to the main query or drop it.
4. **line 35-41**

   - It's 2019.  Please use ANSI JOINs
5. **line 34**

   - There are duplicate column names in a SELECT statement.  Give one of them an alias.

Most likely, your problem will be fixed by (5)

Comment: To be honest the order by in that place just slows down the query as oracle doesn't need it when joining to other tables in the main query which will most likely mess with the order again anyway.